Is it possible to teach TOML Kit how to dump an object?
I am generating TOML files with several tables using TOML Kit without any problem in general.
So far all the values were either strings or numbers, but today I first bumped into a problem. I was trying to dump a pathlib.Path object and it fails with a ConvertError Unable to convert an object of <class 'pathlib.WindowsPath'> to a TOML item. I fixed right away, adding a str in front, but I was thinking to do something valid in general.
Is there a way to teach TOML Kit how to convert a custom object to a valid TOML value? In the case of Path, would be extremely easy.

You want https://tomlkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#tomlkit.register_encoder
Which you would use like this:
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any

import tomlkit
from tomlkit.items import Item, String, ConvertError

class PathItem(String):
    def unwrap(self) -> Path:
        return Path(super().unwrap())

def path_encoder(obj: Any) -> Item:
    if isinstance(obj, Path):
        return PathItem.from_raw(str(obj))
    else:
        # we cannot convert this, but give other custom converters a
        # chance to run
        raise ConvertError

tomlkit.register_encoder(path_encoder)

obj = {'path': Path('/foo/bar')}
document = tomlkit.dumps(obj)
assert document == '''\
path = "/foo/bar"
'''


Exactly that! Thanks
